# Firestore RecyclerView E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I use Firestore RecyclerView but my list does not show up and my logcat says

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Previously, I made this for a spinner listener and it worked, but when I make it like in this code, it causes an error and does not show the list.

I am sorry about renaming java.class

jurnaladapter for adapter
jurnal_sikap_adapter for model class

```
public class detail_siswa extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebase;
    private String documentid;
    private String pre_pengetahuan,post_pengetahuan,sikap,keterampilan,deskripsi,designpattern,coverbuku,kelasid;
    ArrayList<String> pretest,posttest;
    ArrayList<Float> pretest_int,posttest_int;
    private LineChart pretestgraph,posttestgraph;
    private Double skorketerampilan,skordesignpattern,skorcover;
    private TextView skoreterendah,skortertinggi,skorterendah2,skorterrtinggi2,designpatterntv,coverbukutv,ratatv,sikaptv;
    private CollectionReference doc;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewx;
    private jurnaladapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_siswa);

        firebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        skoreterendah = findViewById(R.id.skorterendah);
        skortertinggi = findViewById(R.id.skortertinggi);
        skorterendah2 = findViewById(R.id.postskorterendah);
        skorterrtinggi2 = findViewById(R.id.postskortertinggi);
        designpatterntv = findViewById(R.id.designpatterntampil);
        coverbukutv = findViewById(R.id.coverbukutampil);
        ratatv = findViewById(R.id.rataratatampil);
        sikaptv = findViewById(R.id.sikaptampil);
        pretestgraph = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.pretest_graph);
        posttestgraph =(LineChart) findViewById(R.id.posttest_graph);
        recyclerViewx = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_jurnalsikapxml);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namasiswa_tampil);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String nama = i.getStringExtra("nama");
        kelasid = i.getStringExtra("kelasid");
        textView.setText(nama +" : "+kelasid);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerViewx.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        firebase.collection("kelas").document(kelasid).collection("siswa").whereEqualTo("nama",nama)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                    documentid = documentSnapshot.getId();
                                    kelas kelas = documentSnapshot.toObject(kelas.class);

                                    pre_pengetahuan = kelas.getPre_pengetahuan();
                                    post_pengetahuan = kelas.getPost_pengetahuan();
                                    sikap = kelas.getSikap();
                                    keterampilan = kelas.getKeterampilan();
                                    deskripsi = kelas.getDeskripsi();
                                    designpattern = kelas.getDesignpattern();
                                    coverbuku = kelas.getCoverbuku();
                                }
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        setuprecycleview();
                                    }
                                });

                                convertntampil();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


    private void setuprecycleview() {
        Query query = firebase.collection("kelas").document(kelasid).collection("siswa").document(documentid).collection("jurnalsikap").orderBy("butir", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<jurnal_sikap_adapter> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<jurnal_sikap_adapter>()
                .setQuery(query, jurnal_sikap_adapter.class).build();

        adapter = new jurnaladapter(options);
        recyclerViewx.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewx.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

I edited my adapter. Maybe I got something wrong in my adapter:

```
public class jurnaladapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<jurnal_sikap_adapter, jurnaladapter.jurnalholder> {

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public jurnaladapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<jurnal_sikap_adapter> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull jurnalholder jurnalholder, int i, @NonNull jurnal_sikap_adapter jurnal_sikap_adapter) {
        jurnalholder.catatantv.setText(jurnal_sikap_adapter.getCatatan());
        jurnalholder.butirtv.setText(jurnal_sikap_adapter.getButir());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public jurnalholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.jurnal_sikap_model,parent,false);
        return  new jurnalholder(v);
    }

    class jurnalholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView catatantv;
        TextView butirtv;

        public jurnalholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            catatantv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.catatansikap);
            butirtv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butirSikap);
        }
    }
}
```

this my firestore 
[image]
[image]
[image]
this my model class
[image: this model class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `startListening()` before setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView` as below:

```
private void setuprecycleview() {
    Query query = firebase.collection("kelas").document(kelasid).collection("siswa").document(documentid).collection("jurnalsikap").orderBy("butir", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<jurnal_sikap_adapter> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<jurnal_sikap_adapter>()
            .setQuery(query, jurnal_sikap_adapter.class).build();

    adapter = new jurnaladapter(options);
    recyclerViewx.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerViewx.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: @AiHaQ can you remove the runOnUi... and just call `setuprecycleview();`

Comment: i remove it, but nothing changes

Comment: i try make new query where don't need documentid (just for try ) collection("jurnalsikap"), and i think maybe FirestoreRecyclerOptions not work inside oncomplete and result there no error no adapter attached, but it still not show and error like this E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null

Comment: it show E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout when i put setuprecycleview() inside oncomplete

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to first set the adapter to the view, and only then start listening on it:

```
adapter = new jurnaladapter(options);
recyclerViewx.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerViewx.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.startListening();
```

Comment: i am sorry, it still show same error ` E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you set the adapter from a background thread which is implemented by firebase, you should probably set the adapter to your recyclerview on the Main UI Thread:

**So in your Query callback after the for loop:**

Instead of this:

```
......
......
setuprecycleview();
convertntampil();
.......
.......
```

Do this:

```
......
......

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override 
public void run(){

//call this on UI Thread
setuprecycleview();

}

});

convertntampil();
.....
....
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay I am assuming that the query you build is not correct, you are using documentid twice.

this:

```
Query query = firebase.collection("kelas").document(documentid).collection("siswa").document(documentid).collection("jurnalsikap").orderBy("butir", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

I think must be like this:

```
Query query = firebase.collection("kelas").document(kelasid).collection("siswa").document(documentid).collection("jurnalsikap").orderBy("butir", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Did you do what what I told you, after the for loop.

Comment: Show a screenShot of the database and expose everything.

Comment: you didnt show all the database, you can add another screenshot for the previous collection and docs.

Comment: i wrong in query..in first document i should insert kelasid variable , i change it know error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: How is your kelasid null?

Comment: omg, i has been fix kelasid variable,but his back E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, i will edited question

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: maybe,i declaration kelasid variable twice

Comment: I don't know it seems your `kelasid` is not correctly passed so check that, But it seems to be problem in the way you build the query.

Comment: maybe i should write coding again